# My Spring Database (H2) is not Persisting

Tags: spring, h2, embedded-database

This is my config file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("MyDB").setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("schema.sql").build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);        
}
}
```

After I run the program, I can not find the "MyDB" database.

I know it is an in-memory database. How to make it embedded so that when I close the program the data on the database persist and I can find "MyDB" on the project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public DataSource h2DataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

driver: org.h2.Driver
url: jdbc:h2:file:${java.io.tmpdir}/database/db_name;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
username: user
password: pass
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer a little.

Comment: instead of defining the datasource the way you are doing it now, follow my code sample..

Comment: @blueray This creates a file based database. http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases